# multiplier algebra of a non-unital $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given any infinite dimensional  unital $C^*$ algebra $A$,does there must exist a non-unital $C^*$ algebra $B$ such that the multiplier algebra $M(B)$ of $B$ is $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The multiplier algebra of $M(B)$ of $B$ has $B$ as an essential ideal. So any simple $A$ will be a counterexample.